# Different summary results from R linear regression model

Tags: r, linear-regression

Here is my code:

```
m1 <- lm(Y ~ dummy, data)
```

The 'dummy' contains 12 distinct variables (a1,a2,a3,a4,b1,b2,b3,b4,b5,b6,b7,c). We are using same data but get different result. Here is the summary of my mod:

```
Coefficients:
                 Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)      
a2     
a3     
a4     
b1    
b2     
b3      
b4   
b5   
b6     
b7    
c
```

Here is the result my teammate got:

```
Coefficients:
                 Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)        
b7    
b6     
b5      
b4   
b3   
b2     
b1
c
a1     
a2     
a3
```

From my perspective, my model is making 'a1' as the comparison while the other model is making 'a4' as the comparison and that's the difference.

If I have to get the summary result same as my teammate, what can I do in R ?

Comment: arrange the data the same way

Comment: Read `?relevel`.

Comment: Thanks, 'relevel' works perfect!